# VueJS component display and pass item to component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using VueJS 2.0 and vue-router 2 and am trying to show a template based on route parameters. I am using one view (WidgetView) and changing components displayed in that view. Initially I show a widget list component (WidgetComponent), then when the used selects a widget or the new button in in the WidgetComponent in the WidgetView I want to swap the WidgetComponent out and display the WidgetDetails component, and pass information to that component:

WidgetComponent.vue:

```
<template>
...
<router-link :to="{ path: '/widget_view', params: { widgetId: 'new' }  }"><a> New Widget</a></router-link>
<router-link :to="{ path: '/widget_view', params: { widgetId: widget.id } }"><span>{{widget.name}}</span></router-link>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'WidgetComponent',
    data() {
      return {
        widgets: [{ id: 1,
        name: 'widgetX',
        type: 'catcher'
      }]}
    }
  }
</script>
```

WidgetView.vue

```
<template>
  <component :is="activeComponent"></component>
</template>
<script>
  import WidgetComponent from './components/WidgetComponent'
  import WidgetDetail from './components/WidgetDetail'
  export default {
    name: 'WidgetView',
    components: {
      WidgetComponent,
      WidgetDetail
    },
    mounted: function () {
      const widgetId = this.$route.params.widgetId
      if (widgetId === 'new') {
        // I want to pass the id to this component but don't know how
        this.activeComponent = 'widget-detail'
      }
      else if (widgetId > 0) {
        // I want to pass the id to this component but don't know how
        this.activeComponent = 'widget-detail'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      '$route': function () {
        if (this.$route.params.widgetId === 'new') {
          // how to pass id to this compent?
          this.activeComponent = 'widget-detail'
        }
        else if (this.$route.params.widgetId > 0){
          // how to pass id to this compent?
          this.activeComponent = 'widget-detail'
        }
        else {
          this.activeComponent = 'widget-component'
        }
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        activeComponent: 'widget-component',
        widgetId: 0
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

WidgetDetail.vue

```
<template>
<option v-for="manufacturer in manufacturers" >
    {{ manufacturer.name }}
</option>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
     props: ['sourcesId'],
     ...etc...
   }
</script>
```

router.js

```
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/widget_view',
      component: WidgetView,
      subRoutes: {
        path: '/new',
        component: WidgetDetail
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/widget_view/:widgetId',
      component: WidgetView
    },
  ]
```

})

I couldnt get route paramers working but I managed to get routes working by hard coding the route ie

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/widget_view/'+ 'new' }"> New Widget</router-link>
```

But I dont know how to pass an id to the given template from the script (not template) code in WidgetView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example http://jsfiddle.net/ognc78e7/1/. Try using the `router-view` element hold your components. Also, use props inside components to pass in variables from the URL. The docs explain it much better http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

```
//routes
{ path: '/foo/:id', component: Bar, props:true }
//component
const Bar = { template: '<div>The id is {{id}}</div>',props:['id'] }
```

Not sure which way you want it, but you could have the `/foo/` path actually be the creation widget and then have the dynamic `/foo/:id` path. Or you could do like I did here and the foo path is like a start page that links to different things.